# Javascript map 2 arrays into 1 Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary

I have to arrays (Name and State Array) and map them togther into one object with the attrbiutes name and state.

Array Name:

```
 ["Time", "Riskchanged", "Scope", "Risk4", "Test", "Test(2)"]
```

Array State:

```
 ["In Bearbeitung", "Abgeschlossen", "In Bearbeitung", "Abgeschlossen", "Geplant", "In Bearbeitung"]
```

Function:

```
this.testArr = this.riskNamesArr.map( (x, i) => {
    return {"name": x, "state": this.riskWorkflowStateArr[i]}        
});
```

This works perfect on all Desktop Browsers but unfortunately not on my iOS Safari Browser.. The mobile Browser just shows nothing if I add those lines..

So is there another approach to get the same result?

Comment: Have you tried using the anonymous function in place of the Arrow function expression, does iOS Safari support ES6?

Comment: Like @simplesystems says, it would be a good idea to [check the ES? compatibility here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think thats a problem with the arrow-function - thats ES6-style. Try using a simple function:

```
testArr = riskNamesArr.map( function(x, i){
    return {"name": x, "state": riskWorkflowStateArr[i]}        
}.bind(this));
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/urbr49d3/

Comment: btw no need for bind, use thisArg. `testArr = riskNamesArr.map( function(x, i){
    return {"name": x, "state": riskWorkflowStateArr[i]}        
}, this);`

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

Safari for iOS [does not yet support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) arrow functions `() => {}`. Use a normal function `function() {}` instead:

```
var riskWorkflowStateArr = this.riskWorkflowStateArr;
this.testArr = this.riskNamesArr.map(function(x, i) {
    return {"name": x, "state": riskWorkflowStateArr[i]}        
});
```

[More about arrow functions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

**Edit:** Changed invalid `this` reference.

Comment: this results in a  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: @simplesystems see my edit. In normal functions, the `this` reference does not necessarily point to the `this` reference of the surrounding block. In arrow functions, it does.

Answer (score -3):

Add this header on the server side responses to POST requests:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I suppose it's a cache problem, but not entirely sure. If it doesn't work. Please tell me and I will try to find another reason it's not working

Comment: This was a suggestion, a possible answer. I don't see why it should get a `-1`. The downvotes are related to the quality of the answer, not if it is the answer you were looking for or not.